# Target .NET 8 Release Candidate Version in VS2022

Tags: .net, .net-core, .net-8.0

I am waiting for a host provider to update their server version of .NET 8 from 8.0.0-rc.2.23479.6 but they are dragging their heels.  Is it possible to target this specific version within Visual Studio so I can build and deploy whilst I wait for them to update their servers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need/want concrete SDK to be used for build/publish then you can use [`global.json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json) to "fix" it. Install corresponding SDK and add `global.json` to the project root with specific SDK version and disabled roll-forwarding:

```json
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "8.0.0-rc.2.23479.6",
    "rollForward": "disable"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this.  can I also ask if I can have both .net 8 and the .net 8 rc sdks installed on the same machine or am I likely to hit issues?  I don't want to install it to find it causes conflicts with the current version of 8 on my machine - thanks in advance!

Comment: @StephenGarside I have a lot of SDKs installed on my machine and for now have not experienced any issues.

Comment: Thanks for this, worked a treat and got me out of a hole :)  I had to drop the global.json file in the same folder as my solution as it has multiple projects.

Comment: @StephenGarside was glad to help! _"I had to drop the global.json file in the same folder as my solution as it has multiple projects"_ - yes, sorry for not ideal wording, project root meant the root of repo and/or where the sln file is placed.